# Different return values of `String#split` method using regex

Tags: ruby, regex

Why does the second `split` in the following return the punctuation? Why does using parentheses in the regular expression change the output?

```
str = "This is a test string. Let's split it."

str.split(/\. /)
# =>["This is a test string", "Let's split it."]

str.split(/(\. )/)
# =>["This is a test string", ". ", "Let's split it."]
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with Ruby. It is the regex behavior. Same in Perl

Comment: Aaaaah this and Yu's answer make a ton of sense. Thanks.

Comment: @texasbruce, It has everything to do with Ruby. `String#split()` is defined to do that.  Ruby borrows many things from perl, and it so happens perl also defines split()  to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the second code uses a regex that contains a group. From [`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-split):

> If pattern is a `Regexp`, `str` is divided where the pattern matches. Whenever the pattern matches a zero-length string, str is split into individual characters. **If pattern contains groups, the respective matches will be returned in the array as well.**